# Geometry nodes - Material Existing boolean value

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes

Is there way to return boolean value from **Material Selection Node** if it's empty or has material?

For example, i want to use it **with switch nodes**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *Attribute Statistic* node to obtain a constant (single) value type from a field:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to check, if a *Material Selection* node is empty, you can compare it against another one, that is empty:

## False

[image]

## True

[image]

Comment: I tried this but the Result won't work with a swith statement